# Why is my Java Discord Bot not connecting to my sqlite dadabase?

Tags: linux, sqlite, server, debian, bots

I programmed a discord bot with java for some minecraft project I am going to make.
I bought a KVM V-Server, installed all I needed and uploaded my bot's files including my prepared sqlite database.

But the problem is: When I execute my start.sh, there is an error code.

```
root@5030 /home/Bot $ ./start.sh
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:Datenbank.db
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:689)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
        at de.nameddaniel.bot.main.LiteSQL.connect(LiteSQL.java:35)
        at de.nameddaniel.bot.main.Main.<init>(Main.java:50)
        at de.nameddaniel.bot.main.Main.main(Main.java:42)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at de.nameddaniel.bot.main.LiteSQL.onUpdate(LiteSQL.java:64)
        at de.nameddaniel.bot.main.SQLManager.onCreate(SQLManager.java:9)
        at de.nameddaniel.bot.main.Main.<init>(Main.java:51)
        at de.nameddaniel.bot.main.Main.main(Main.java:42)
```

I searched on google for help. There, in some forums, people said, that you should insert `Class.forName();` before connecting to the database.
I did so but it did not help:

```
public static void connect() {

        c = null;
        
        try {
            File file = new File("Datenbank.db");
            
            if(!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();
                
            }
            String url = "jdbc:sqlite:" + file.getPath();
            try {
                Class.forName(LiteSQL.class.getName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            
            System.out.println("Verbindung zu Datenbank hergestellt.");
            
            s = c.createStatement();
        }
        catch(SQLException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I am executing connect() in my Main class:

```
public Main() {
        instance = this;
        LiteSQL.connect();
        SQLManager.onCreate();
        
        try {
            jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(BotToken.token).build();
        } catch (LoginException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        jda.getPresence().setActivity(Activity.watching("dir zu."));
        jda.getPresence().setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE);
                
//      audioPlayerManager = new DefaultAudioPlayerManager();
//      playermanager = new PlayerManager();
        cmdMan = new CommandManager();
        
        jda.addEventListener(new CommandListener());
        jda.addEventListener(new VoiceListener());
        jda.addEventListener(new ReactionListener());
        jda.addEventListener(new RoleListener());
        jda.addEventListener(new JoinListener());
        jda.addEventListener(new NicknameListener());
        jda.addEventListener(new AvatarChangeListener());
        jda.addEventListener(new BanListener());
        
        System.out.println("Bot wurde hochgefahren");
        
//      AudioSourceManagers.registerRemoteSources(audioPlayerManager);
//      audioPlayerManager.getConfiguration().setFilterHotSwapEnabled(true);
        
        shutdown();
        runLoop();
                
    }
```

So, how do I fix that?
If there is any information missing, please tell me. As well if you need translations.
Hope you can help me,
Daniel :D

Comment: I installed sqlite3 but it still does not work

Comment: Wer den veralteten code von CoasterFreak nutzt... Steig am besten auf MongoDB als Datenbank um das ist viel performanter und einfacher als SQLLite